# Avoid n+1 query when indexing on elasticsearch rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, elasticsearch

I have a `Genre` model which have it's name translated in a genre_translations table (using the [globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) gem)

I'm trying to indexing the model using the [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) gem

```
def as_indexed_json(options = {})
  as_json(
    only: %i(type available),
    methods: %i(name),
  )
end
```

but when I do `Genre.import` I get the following on my rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> Genre.import
  Genre Load (27.1ms)  SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres"  ORDER BY "genres"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
  Genre::Translation Load (23.9ms)  SELECT "genre_translations".* FROM "genre_translations" WHERE "genre_translations"."genre_id" = $1  [["genre_id", 1]]
  Genre::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "genre_translations".* FROM "genre_translations" WHERE "genre_translations"."genre_id" = $1  [["genre_id", 2]]
  Genre::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "genre_translations".* FROM "genre_translations" WHERE "genre_translations"."genre_id" = $1  [["genre_id", 3]]
  ...
```

Any suggestion on how to index all the `Genre` items with a join to avoid the N+1 behaviour?

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you mean by "the N+1 behaviour"?  What is your actual problem?

Comment: @MaxWilliams The problem is that when getting the data from the genres and genres_translations tables, it should do it on a single query. It shouldn't be doing a query to get the genres and then 1 query for each genre to get the name. You can find a detailed explanation here: http://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the doc [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/b40479d371836f303dd8aaabed33a75d5de2898f/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb#L71-L73)

```
    # @example Pass an ActiveRecord query to limit the imported records
    #
    #    Article.import query: -> { where(author_id: author_id) }
```

So you could do:

```
 Genre.import query: -> { includes(:translations) }
```